# views query alter not working when view appears in sidebar

Tags: blocks, views

I have a block view, and I want to change my query, to add contextual filter. I made a views query alter but when the view appears in sidebar as block view this function doesn't work.

```
function bpm_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
   if ($view->name == 'single_job' && $view->display_handler->display->id =='block_1' ){
      $nid = _get_job_nid_from_url();
      $query->where[1]['conditions'][2]['value'] = $nid;
   }
}
```

If I add the same block view in page content then views query alter work as expected. The page is created by page callback and this is following code how i add block view in page content

```
$output = views_embed_view('single_job', $display_id = 'block_1', $category);
```

Comment: in views_embed_view, shouldn't $category be $nid?

Comment: yes it is $nid, but I copy just a piece of my code.
 
I don't have a problem with $output, i just added that to show how everything works perfect with views_post_render. But views post render prints $output in page['content'] not in sidebar. I need to print view in sidebar and I want to assign $nid as contextual filter.

Answer (score 1):

I think you problem is there that $nid not passed correctly,edit your views, instead of your filter, set filter by contextual filter then in your page passed it by contextual filter parameter with

```
$view= views_embed_view('single_job', $display_id = 'block_1', $category);
$view->set_arguments(array($node->nid));
$output = $view->preview();
print $output;
```

not longer  need query alter function

```
/*
function bpm_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ($view->name == 'single_job' && $view->display_handler->display->id =='block_1' ){
    $nid = _get_job_nid_from_url();
  $query->where[1]['conditions'][2]['value'] = $nid; 
 }
}*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the values from the url with $view->args[0] or $_GET['q'].